# Common distribution with sharper edges?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Normal probability distribution is common, but it has only mean and stdev parameters being well defined. There are no singular points which could serve as minimum and maximum (all suggestions like 3 sigma are conditional).

Is there any common distribution with sharper edges and which implies well defined edge points?

Answer (score 1):

A uniform distribution on an interval $[a,b]$ is used when you measure a parameter within a given error.  That's about as sharp as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

A lot! For example, [Wigner's semi-circle distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_semicircle_distribution) has density $\frac2{\pi r^2}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ for $x$ in $(-r,r)$ and $0$ elsewhere.